# Can a sound wave have such high frequency that it causes permanent displacement of medium?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, elasticity

Is it possible to have a sound wave with frequency so high that it causes permanent displacement of matter (the frequency is greater than the elasticity of the medium, so the medium is unable to return to original position)

If this is possible, what frequency would this occur at?

Comment: Maybe if the frequency causes resonance, like a glass shattering from a high pitched voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound can cause permanent shift in the medium, but the condition is that the wave must not be perfectly sinusoidal; i.e. the sound must be made of multiple frequencies. The waves must superimpose to give a wave that can be represented as a function which is not an oscilatory function.